# Site url getting overridden using rails oauth2 plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I am using ruby oauth2 gem

I have my site URL as 
`site = "https://192.168.5.15:9443/oauth2/authorize"`
but once i call
`client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => redirect_uri)`

My URL is changed to 
`https://192.168.5.15:9443/oauth/authorize?client_id=J7H_LoEIdaf9aVXF_opqtVMLgwoa&redirect_uri`

So my `oauth2/authorize` is being replaced by `oauth/authorize`

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `:authorize_url` attribute.

```
require 'oauth2'
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :authorize_url => '/oauth2/authorize', :site => 'https://192.168.5.15:9443')
```